# BadMethodCallException | Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::whereRaw does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling, migration

in Larevel, I can't migrate this table "Favorites", I faced this error

> (Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::whereRaw does not exist.),

I tried to use 'orWhere' and 'where' instead but it is useless cause of the same error... this is my code.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFavoritesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->enum('item_type', ['question', 'answer']);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('item_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->unique(['user_id', 'item_type', 'item_id']);

            $connection = Schema::getConnection()->getDriverName();

            if ($connection === 'mysql') {
                $table->foreign('item_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('questions')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->whereRaw('(item_type = "answer" AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answers WHERE id = favorites.item_id))');
            } else {
                $table->morphTo('item');
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('favorites');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can have a `where` clause on `ON DELETE` options

Comment: @aynber seems (codewise) they are trying to apply it directly to the schema builder, not even a fluent field

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `$table->whereRaw(...)` and `$table->morphTo('item')` inside of a Migration makes no sense... Also, `$table` is a [`Blueprint`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html) class, but the methods you're trying to use are part of the [`Builder`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html) and [`Model`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) classes...

Comment: @lagbox Right, but it seems like an X/Y problem. `where` clauses are part of the QueryBuilder, not the SchemaBuilder, but they're also trying to apply a `where` clause to a table schema that doesn't support it. It seems like this type of delete cascade should be on the model or model event, not in the schema.